# awk print all lines except those before match

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this file

```
john
robert
rose*
ann*
charles
david
liz*
louis
wendy*
kate*
mandy*
paul
```

I want to print all lines except those lines before '*'
So the desired output is:

```
john
rose*
ann*
charles
liz*
wendy*
kate*
mandy*
paul
```

I tried with:

```
awk '/\*/ {f=1}; (!f &&NR > 1) {print p}; {p=$0;f=0} END {print p}' file
```

it generates the output

```
john
ann*
charles
liz*
mandy*
paul
```

what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rose*` is a line before `*` (`ann*`) so your criteria of `I want to print all lines except those lines before '*'` doesn't match your expected output and your code appears to do what you say you want.

To instead print all lines that include `*` and/or are not succeeded by lines that include `*` and so get the expected output you show would be:

```
$ awk '(NR>1) && ((p ~ /\*/) || !/\*/){print p} {p=$0} END{print p}' file
john
rose*
ann*
charles
liz*
wendy*
kate*
mandy*
paul
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly just for my personal enjoyment.

A `sed` command that solves the same problem:

```bash
sed -e 'N' -e '/[^*]$/P' -e '/[*]\n.*[*]$/P' -e '$!D' -e 's/.*\n//' file
```

This maintains two lines from the input in the edit buffer.  The next line is added to the edit buffer using `N`, and is delimited from the already existing data by a literal newline character inserted by `sed`.

If there is no `*` at the end of the buffer, the initial part of the buffer is printed with `P`. This is what outputs a line if a non-starred line follows it.

If the buffer contains a `*` followed by a literal newline character (i.e. the first part of the buffer ends with a `*`) *and* there is a `*` at the end of the buffer; then the first part is printed with `P`.  This is what outputs a starred line even if another starred line follows it.

The `D` deletes the initial part of the buffer unless we've reached the end.  The `D` command also automatically causes the script to start from the first instruction (but without emptying the whole edit buffer or automatically reading another line of input, like `d` would do).

If we reach the `s` command at the end, we've read the last line and the last two lines are in the buffer.  The first of these ought to have been printed (or not) already, so we only need to make sure that we delete that before allowing the remaining final line to be printed.

A shorter variant:

```bash
sed -e '$q' -e 'N' -e '/[^*]$/P' -e '/[*]\n.*[*]$/P' -e 'D' file
```

This relies on the fact that the unconditional `D` command at the end will also trim off the penultimate line kept in the edit buffer, and we accept a final iteration which is cut short by the `$q` at the start of the script, causing the script to terminate after printing the final line.

Answer (score 1):

In case `sed` is acceptable

```
sed '/\*$/!{$!N;//!P;D;}' file
```

For lines not ending with `*`: read the `N`ext line, and if there's still no match, then print the first line. `D` removes the first line and repeats the process.